# Scope conditions are not rendering in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a scope on the Messages model so that it only lists messages where the conversation_id is NULL. However after adding it made no changes to the inbox as it still shows messages with a conversation_id.

Can someone point out what I did wrong?

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :inbox, -> {where('conversation_id IS NULL')}
  scope :unread, -> {where('read_at IS NULL')}
```

Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    @messages = Message.scoped
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archived"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
    if params[:mailbox] == "unread"
    @messages = @user.unread_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  if params[:mailbox] == "trash"
    @messages = @user.deleted_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to call the scope in controller, i believe that is:

```
elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
  @messages = @user.received_messages.inbox.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are making a scope `inbox` but you are not using it in the controller. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. I totally overlook that.